# <FeatureRef> cannot be sorted!

Tags: wix

i have few files let say setup.wxs, client.wxs and report.wxs. pratically, client.wxs and report.wxs each has its own <.FeatureRef Id="MainApplication"> to the main <.Feature Id="MainApplication" ...>. but the funniest thing is, i cannot sort the tree order.

let say i want:

MainApp
 |- Client
 |- Report

Unfortunately, it will come out the result with:

MainApp
 |- Report
 |- Client

unless i put these all features into the main setup.wsx without <.FeatureRef>. by this way, i can sort them as what i wanted.

can any help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. If you want to control the order, then you need to put FeatureRef or Feature elements in the correct order under the MainApp Feature. Limitiation of the WiX toolset (that no one has complained about until now ;).

You could probably open a feature request against the WiX toolset.